# Moving average sticks in fictitious zeroes for the first readings. This delays accuracy

Tags: arduino-uno

My 9/10 Moving Average inserts zeroes for the first 9 readings. For example, if the first voltage reading is 100, the first moving average given is 10. That is the average of 9 zeroes and one 100. How can I get the moving average to only use actual readings from the adc? Or how can I get the moving average to wait until at least 10 readings are finished before starting its calculations?

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ads1262.h>

#define PGA 1 // Programmable Gain = 1
#define VREF 2.50 // Internal reference of 2.048V
#define VFSR VREF/PGA             
#define FSR (((long int)1<<23)-1)  

ads1262 PC_ADS1262; // class

float volt_V=0;
float volt_mV=0;
float MovingAverage=0;
volatile int i;
volatile char SPI_RX_Buff[10];
volatile long ads1262_rx_Data[10];
volatile static int SPI_RX_Buff_Count = 0;
volatile char *SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr;
volatile int Responsebyte = false;
volatile signed long sads1262Count = 0;
volatile signed long uads1262Count=0;
double resolution;

void setup() {
  // initalize the  data ready and chip select pins:
  pinMode(ADS1262_DRDY_PIN, INPUT); //data ready input line
  pinMode(ADS1262_CS_PIN, OUTPUT); //chip enable output line
  pinMode(ADS1262_START_PIN, OUTPUT);  // start
  pinMode(ADS1262_PWDN_PIN, OUTPUT); // Power down output
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //initalize ADS1292 slave
  PC_ADS1262.ads1262_Init(); // initialise ads1262
  Serial.println("ads1262 Initialised successfully....");
}

void loop() {
  volatile int i, data;
  if((digitalRead(ADS1262_DRDY_PIN)) == LOW) {
    // monitor Data   ready(DRDY pin)
    SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr = PC_ADS1262.ads1262_Read_Data();
    // read 6 bytes conversion register
    Responsebyte = true;
  }
  if(Responsebyte == true) {
    for(i = 0; i <5; i++) {
      SPI_RX_Buff[SPI_RX_Buff_Count++] = *(SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr + i);
    }
    Responsebyte = false;
  }
  if(SPI_RX_Buff_Count >= 5) {
    ads1262_rx_Data[0]= (unsigned char)SPI_RX_Buff[1];
    // read 4 bytes adc count
    ads1262_rx_Data[1]= (unsigned char)SPI_RX_Buff[2];
    ads1262_rx_Data[2]= (unsigned char)SPI_RX_Buff[3];
    ads1262_rx_Data[3]= (unsigned char)SPI_RX_Buff[4];
    uads1262Count = (signed long) (((unsigned long)ads1262_rx_Data[0]<<24)| ((unsigned long)ads1262_rx_Data[1]<<16)|(ads1262_rx_Data[2]<<8)|        ads1262_rx_Data[3]);
    //get the raw 32-bit adc count out by shifting
    sads1262Count = (signed long) (uads1262Count);
    // get signed value
    resolution = (double)((double)VREF/pow(2,31));
    //resolution=  Vref/(2^n-1) , Vref=2.5, n=no of bits
    volt_V = (resolution)*(float)sads1262Count;
    // voltage = resolution * adc count
    MovingAverage = (9*MovingAverage + volt_V)/10;
    Serial.print(MovingAverage,8);
  }
  SPI_RX_Buff_Count = 0;
}

float mapfloat(float x, float in_min, float in_max, float out_min, float out_max) {
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```

Comment: Why are almost all variables volatile? Why do you have two variables called `i` (one global and one in loop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are essentially two ways of initializing a low pass filter. The
first is to let it initialize itself “naturally” by feeding it data
until it reaches its steady state. This is the approach of jwpat7's
answer, and it works really well with [FIR filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response), like a plain
moving average.

Your exponentially-weighted moving average, however, is an
[IIR filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response). Given constant input, it converges *asymptotically* to its
steady state. After feeding it 10 values, it will only have reached 65%
of the steady state (exactly 1 − 0.9<sup>10</sup>), thus you
may want to feed it significantly more than 10 points. E.g., you should
give it 22 points if you want it to be 90% initialized.

The other approach is to provision a specific initialization procedure
that sets the internal state of the filter to what it would have been
had it processed an infinite stream of constant values. This is actually
really easy to do with this particular filter, as we only have to set
the output equal to its first input. Here is the self-initializing
filter written as a function (this keeps the code cleaner):

```
static float movingAverage(float x)
{
  static bool initialized;
  static float output;

  // Initialize the filter as if this input had been on forever.
  if (!initialized) {
    output = x;
    initialized = true;
  }

  output += 0.1 * (x - output);
  return output;
}
```

You loose the benefit of the averaging on the very first data points,
but in return you have a simple to use self-initializing filter.

Unrelated to your question, I looked at your code and fond so many
confusing and useless statements that I felt compelled to remove all
that cruft. I did not test the simplified version though:

```
#include <ads1262.h>

const float VREF = 2.50;  // Internal reference

ads1262 PC_ADS1262;  // ADC object

void setup() {
  // initialize the  data ready and chip select pins:
  pinMode(ADS1262_DRDY_PIN,  INPUT);   // data ready input line
  pinMode(ADS1262_CS_PIN,    OUTPUT);  // chip enable output line
  pinMode(ADS1262_START_PIN, OUTPUT);  // start
  pinMode(ADS1262_PWDN_PIN,  OUTPUT);  // power down output
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // initialize ADS1292 slave
  PC_ADS1262.ads1262_Init();
  Serial.println("ads1262 Initialised successfully....");
}

static float movingAverage(float x) { ... }  // as before

void loop() {
  // Nothing to do unless data ready is asserted.
  if (digitalRead(ADS1262_DRDY_PIN) == HIGH) return;

  // Get a reading and convert to voltage.
  uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *) PC_ADS1262.ads1262_Read_Data();
  signed long reading = (uint32_t) buffer[1] << 24
                      | (uint32_t) buffer[2] << 16
                      | (uint32_t) buffer[3] <<  8
                      | (uint32_t) buffer[4] <<  0;
  float voltage = VREF / (1UL<<31) * reading;

  // Report a smoothed-out reading.
  Serial.println(movingAverage(voltage), 8);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Edgar, your simplified codes works fine. I'm obviously no expert on coding. The lesson on filters is very interesting. I'm still playing around with what will work best with this weigh scale project. I plan to try a precision voltage reference instead of the Arduino 5 volt source. I know there is a method of connecting the B+ to other adc inputs and checking B+ continuously to achieve more stability and precision. I'll probably be back to this forum again, this is great!

Comment: Edgar, could you please show me how to slow the sample rate in your simplified sketch?

Comment: @Rico: Simplest thing would be to add a `delay()` in `loop()`. Cleaner would be to _conditionally_ take the samples, on the condition “it's time to do so”. The approach is clearly explained in the [Blink Without Delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) Arduino tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest way to take in at least 10 readings before beginning to output results is to set a counter to 10 and count it down, as illustrated in following code.

```
byte startup=10;
void loop() {
  stuff_to_await_DRDY_and_compute_volt_V();
  MovingAverage = (9*MovingAverage + volt_V)/10;
  if (startup)
    --startup;  // Don't use MovingAverage during startup cycles
  else {        // Now we are done with startup...
    Serial.print(MovingAverage,8);
    other_stuff_with_new_data();
  }
}
```

As hinted at in a comment to the question, declaring all your variables `volatile` isn't necessary.  You should declare variables that are shared between threads, or between an ISR and `loop()`, `volatile`, but to declare other variables as `volatile` is in general a coding-style error that will confuse whoever maintains the code.  Spurious `volatile` declarations also may increase code size slightly, as it prevents one-time evaluation of expressions that are used exactly the same way multiple times, and it prevents code motion like moving constant expressions out of loops.

The following code rewrites severak parts of your sketch.  It uses some pointer arithmetic to avoid the tedious assignments and shifting found in your code.  It removes several extraneous casts because many of the type promotions and conversions coerced by your casts happen automatically anyway.  This code has not been tested; if it has problems, please point them out and I'll edit accordingly.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ads1262.h>
#define PGA 1 // Programmable Gain = 1
#define VREF 2.50 // Internal reference of 2.048V
#define VFSR VREF/PGA             
#define FSR (((long int)1<<23)-1)  
ads1262 PC_ADS1262; // class
float volt_V=0;
float volt_mV=0;
float MovingAverage=0;
byte SPI_RX_Buff[10];
byte SPI_RX_Buff_Count = 0;
char *SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr;
void setup() {
  // initalize the  data ready and chip select pins:
  pinMode(ADS1262_DRDY_PIN, INPUT); //data ready input line
  pinMode(ADS1262_CS_PIN, OUTPUT); //chip enable output line
  pinMode(ADS1262_START_PIN, OUTPUT);  // start
  pinMode(ADS1262_PWDN_PIN, OUTPUT); // Power down output
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //initalize ADS1292 slave
  PC_ADS1262.ads1262_Init(); // initialise ads1262
  Serial.println("ads1262 Initialised successfully....");
}

byte startup=10;
void loop() {
  double resolution;
  long *ads1262Count;
  if((digitalRead(ADS1262_DRDY_PIN)) == LOW) { // Is data ready?
    resolution = (double)VREF/pow(2,31);  // Vref/(2^n-1), Vref=2.5
    // Get address of 6-byte conversion-data buffer
    SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr = PC_ADS1262.ads1262_Read_Data();
    // Copy address of SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr[1] to ads1262Count
    ads1262Count = SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr+1;
    // Dereference ads1262Count pointer to get 4-byte signed value
    volt_V = *ads1262Count * resolution;
    MovingAverage = (9*MovingAverage + volt_V)/10;
    if (startup)
      --startup; // Don't use MovingAverage during startup cycles
    else {       // Now we are done with startup...
      Serial.print(MovingAverage,8);
      other_stuff_with_new_data();
    }
  }
  SPI_RX_Buff_Count = 0;
}
```

Comment: You do need to move the bytes around: according to the OP's code, the `ads1262_Read_Data()` method returns the data MSB first, whereas the Uno stores numbers in memory LSB first.

Comment: Thank you, your counter method works fine. The lesson on volatiles is very helpful also. I tried your trimmed down code, it showed an error with the void loop line, "ads1262Count = SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr+1;" and the error was "cannot convert 'char*' to 'long int*' in assignment".

Comment: @rico, I forgot to cast it ... s.b. `ads1262Count = (long int*)(SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr+1);` instead.  However, if Edgar Bonet is correct about byte order, copying the bytes is needed anyway.  Will edit answer if I get a chance to check.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is just to go "I have only taken one reading, therefore I only need to look at one reading".  I.e., after your first reading you have 100/1. After your second reading you have (100+100)/2. After your 3726482374th reading you have (100+100+100+100+100+100+100+100+100+100)/10.

I have a fully templated library that works in exactly that way - it returns the rolling average (amongst other things) of only the samples you have actually fed it.

- https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/Average